# Listings not showing line number in standalone class

Tags: listings, standalone, article

I'm trying to compile a listing in a `standalone` so it can be `\includegraphics`'d on a separate document. The line numbers disappear when compiling as `standalone`, however, even though they do appear if the document class is `article`.

MWE

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
numbers=left
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
some
code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Compiling as `standalone`

[image: Compiling as standalone]

Compiling as `article`

[image: Compiling as article]

Comment: Try the varwidth option for standalone.

Comment: `varwidth` didn't work, but that made me think the numbers were there, they were just being cropped. I increased the margin, and it worked! Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a larger margin to include the line numbers:

```
% \documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin={8mm 0 0 0}]{standalone}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
numbers=left,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
some
code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is much better than what I was doing. And I had no idea the `margin` option could receive four separate margins. Thank you!